# display email body of selected email in outlook as a message box in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using excel 2010 and have created the following vba code which finds emails which contain the word test in their subject heading and then in excel it shows a message box with the body of that email:

```
Sub GetFromInbox()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim olFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olItms As Outlook.Items
    Dim olMail As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set olItms = olFldr.Items
    Set objItem = olApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)


    olItms.Sort "Subject"

    i = 1

    For Each olMail In olItms
     If InStr(olMail.Subject, "Test") > 0 Then
            MsgBox olMail.Body
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next olMail

    Set olFldr = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

My ultimate aim here is to add more if conditions to the code, so that only the currently selected email or opened email in outlook has its email body displayed in my excel message box

An example of this is say we have several emails with the subject "test" as it currently stands the code will show the body of all these emails which have the subject "test" one after another in a different message box.

But there should only ever be one message box displayed for the currently selected/opened email in outlook if that emails subject is "test".

Please can someone show me how I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Application.ActiveInsepctor` property to get the opened email or use the `Application.ActiveExplorer` property to get a selected, but unopened, email

```
Sub GetFromInbox()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application

    'If it's not an MailItem or there's no
    'ActiveInspector, error is ignored
    On Error Resume Next
        Set olMail = olApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    On Error GoTo 0

    'If nothing is open, see if a MailItem is selected
    If olMail Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
            Set olMail = olApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

    If Not olMail Is Nothing Then
        If InStr(olMail.Subject, "Test") > 0 Then
            MsgBox olMail.Body
        Else
            MsgBox "Selected/active email does not have correct subject"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Active item is not an email or no email selected"
    End If

End Sub
```

First, it looks for the active, opened item. If that's not an email, then it looks at the first selected item in whatever "Explorer" is active. If that's not an email, then it gives you a message.

If the open, active item is an email, it uses that and tests the subject. In that case it doesn't look at any selected items. Only if there's nothing open or the open item is not a Mailitem (like it's a CalendarItem), does it look at what's selected.

If you're in, say, the calendar, then that's the active explorer and it's likely that any selection is not a MailItem. It also doesn't care if you're in the Inbox of another folder. It only cares if the first item selected is a MailItem. You could check `olapp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder` to make sure you're in the Inbox if that's important to you.

You can have Items in your mail folders that are not MailItems. If it's not a MailItem that's selected, then you'll get a message.

Finally, you can select any number of items in your Inbox. This only looks at the first items selected. If you want to process all the items, you can look through them using `.Selection.Count` and `.Selection.Item(i)` to process each one in turn.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, however I tried this and it doesn't seem to do anything?

Comment: I tested it on my machine and it worked fine. What do you mean it didn't do anything? Was olMail Nothing? Did you get an error? Is there an open email? Did it have "test" in the subject?

Comment: The code doesn't appear to do anything, there's no error, nothing happens physically. The email has test in the subject title, and the email may not necessarily be open hence why i need any code to work of selected email rather than opened email. Are you sure this code can be executed from excel? as I am attempting to execute the code from excel

Comment: Ok apologies, I see that the code does work once the user opens the email. however, is there a way to make this code work based on the email being selected? as my user may not always open their email?

Comment: Ok, I didn't read your question carefully enough. I've adjusted the code to look for an open email or a selected email.